# i am trying to swap between text and image using jquery toggle

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I was trying to use jquery "toggle" to hide the div with text and show an image instead, and vice versa, but when I click on the button it doesn't work. The button is from a bootstrap example: is that what's causing the problem?

**Code** :

```js
$("#btn1").click(function() {
  $("#struttura").toggle();
  $("#foto1").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="struttura">
  lorem ipsum
</div>
<img id="foto1" src="greppistruttura.jpg" style="display: hidden;">
<p><a class="btn btn-secondary" role="button" id="btn1">View details &raquo;</a></p>
```

Comment: Try using show and hide instead of toggle.

Comment: Hi , just add `display:none` to img element. Working code check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mp17wfvo/)

Answer (score 0):

put your code inside jquery code block to run after page load. then add an initial toggle to hide your div and no need to add style to your img .something like this:

```
$(function() {
     $("#struttura").toggle();
     $("#btn1").click(function() {
        $("#struttura").toggle();
        $("#foto1").toggle();
     });
});
```